how to change authority\system to another user
When I run the whoami command, it returns nt authority\system. The question is how I can change nt authority\system to another user?
I did it exactly as described following this link, but it feed back user administrator.
I want it feed back another user. How can I do this?


You could configure another user by clicking at "This account" and browse for your user. Instead of searching you could type in your username manually at "this account". It beginns with your hostname (or domain) backslash and the username.
For example:
domain\username
hostname\username
After clicking "ok" the permission to run as a service (for local users) will be added automatically - if there were not already set.
Please note, that the user you will privilige has to set the permission for reading the files and folder of apache.
